# TextView is always null inside a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

EDIT:

This is how I call the method in fragment.

```
public void setTheTextView(int id) { //id is the id of the tab
    if(parsed==true) { //parsed - ensures if s, p1 are not null
        DummySectionFragment dummy = new DummySectionFragment();
        if(id==0) dummy.setTheText(s, p1);
        else if(id==1) dummy.setTheText(s, p2); 
        else dummy.setTheText(s, p3);
    }
}
```

I have the following fragment which displays text after an AsyncTask is complete. I went through few threads, from which I could gather that we have to use a View to get the TextView instance and then update it. Hence I declared

```
View rView
```

Sadly, it has no effect and the TextView is always null. The fragment is present inside MainActivity.java and it's source code is below.

```
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    TextView tView;
    View rView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy, container, false);
        tView = (TextView)rView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        return rView;
    }

    public void setTheText(ArrayList<String> a, ArrayList<String> b) {  
        Log.d("bh","TextView:"+tView); //Always null here
        if(tView != null) { 
            for(int i=0;i<6;i++) {
                tView.append(a.get(i)+" "+b.get(i)+"\n\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The async task is present as a part of the MainActivity? Accessing an innerclass member from an outer class is not possible.

Comment: Yes, the AsyncTask is present as part of MainActivity. However, I don't call the setTheText method from AsyncTask. I merely send some text from inside the AsyncTask to a outer class method, parse it there, call the setTheText() of the DummySectionFragment. Any which way, could you please tell me what I should do to rectify this error?

Comment: U could call setText method from postExecute method in AsyncTask

Comment: Original post updated. Am I doing something wrong there?

Comment: Where are u calling setTheText method from?

Comment: setTheTextView method is called inside onPostExecute(String result) and this method in turn calls the setTheText method of the DummySectionFragment. Please check the edit in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this one line fixed it.

```
DummySectionFragment dummy = (DummySectionFragment) mViewPager.getAdapter().instantiateItem(mViewPager, id);
```

From this endeavour, I understood that I need to read about Fragments in detail before taking it head on.

```
public void setTheTextView(int id) { 
    if(parsed==true) { 
    DummySectionFragment dummy = (DummySectionFragment) mViewPager.getAdapter().instantiateItem(mViewPager, id);
    if(id==0) dummy.setTheText(s, p1);
    else if(id==1) dummy.setTheText(s, p2); 
    else dummy.setTheText(s, p3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use bellow code because it work properly in my end.
// activity

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

ListView listview;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    DummySectionFragment dummySectionFragment = new DummySectionFragment();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();

    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.layout, dummySectionFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    /*
     * RestClient rc = new RestClient();
     * 
     * // the account key might not work. Please insert your own set.
     * ArrayList<Weather> list1 = rc.getPlaces("", ""); int index = 3;
     * String[] listArray = new String[list1.size()]; StringBuilder sb = new
     * StringBuilder(); int counter = 0; Log.e("N", "listArray::" +
     * list1.size());
     * 
     * for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) { sb.append("\n\nEntry #: " +
     * i); sb.append("\n" + "Title: \"" + list1.get(i).getTitle() + "\"");
     * sb.append("\n" + "Publish Date: \"" + list1.get(i).getPubDate() +
     * "\""); sb.append("\n" + "Condition: \"" + list1.get(i).getCondition()
     * + "\""); sb.append("\n" + "Forecast: \"" + list1.get(i).getForecast()
     * + "\"");
     * 
     * listArray[counter] = sb.toString(); counter++; sb.delete(0,
     * sb.capacity()); } Log.e("N", "listArray::" + listArray.length);
     * 
     * listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
     * android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listArray));
     * 
     * }
     */
}
```

}

// fragment

public class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment

{
    TextView tView;
    View rView;

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frg, container, false);
    tView = (TextView) rView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        arrayList.add("" + i);

        arrayList1.add("" + i + 10);
    }
    setTheText(arrayList, arrayList1);
    return rView;
}

public void setTheText(ArrayList<String> a, ArrayList<String> b) {
    Log.d("bh", "TextView:" + tView); // Always null here
    if (tView != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            tView.append(a.get(i) + " " + b.get(i) + "\n\n");
        }
    }
}
```

}